# XCOPY Command options

Tags: command-line, backup, xcopy

xcopy command used with option /d only compares the dates of the source and destination files. So if the dates are same it overlooks the time stamp of the files to determine which is newer. This results in the newer file with same date but later time stamp not being copied. This plays havoc while creating a backup because so many source files having the same date as destination files but later time stamps do not get copied. This results in a faulty backup.

Can some body please suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try [robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), it's like xcopy but more advanced

> Ability to copy file data and attributes correctly, and to preserve
>   original timestamps, as well as NTFS ACLs, owner information, and
>   audit information using command line switches. (/COPYALL or /COPY:)
>   Copying folder timestamps is also possible in later versions
>   (/DCOPY:T).

Comment: Ok... I’ll ask. What is an esteroid?

Comment: Sorry... steroid... i was thinking in spanish